# Do you have to include a false value in a ternary operator PHP?

Tags: php

I need to add append data to a string if a certain variable is true, if not, I don't need to append anything. Currently I'm doing:

```
$string = (condition()) ? 'something'.$string.'something' : $string;
```

Is there a way to skip adding the false option in a ternary operator? It seems wasteful to say $string = $string if the condition is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't skip it. You could re-write as a one line `if` condition though:

```
if (condition()) $string = 'something'.$string.'something';
```

Comment: This was my next choice but was hoping it could be done. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to skip it. If you want to skip the false bit, go back to the `if` method:

```
if (condition()) $string = 'something' . $string . 'something';
```

The ternary method is just a short-hand `if` statement anyway. If you can make the `if` statement just as short without sacrificing readability (as in the example above), you should consider it.

But, to be honest, I'd even format that to make it *more* readable:

```
if (condition())
    $string = 'something' . $string . 'something';
```

Unless you're desperately short of monitor height, that will be easier to understand at a glance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to. Think of the ternary operator as a function. What would you expect the behaviour to be if you did something like this, but didn't want to make an assignment if `condition()` evaluated to `false`:

```
$string = ternary(condition(), $yesValue, $noValue);
```

There is no way that you can abort the assignment into the variable `$string` if `condition()` evaluates to false.

Comment: Note, this is an excellent thought exercise, but if this short answer is still TL;DR, then note the above code section does not work.   It is not code; it is a analogy.

Answer (score -1):

No. That's the point of a ternary. If you don't want a false value, why not just make condition() return the value you need?

Something like:

```
$string = condition($string);

function condition($string){
    if($string == 'whatever')
    {
        $string = 'something'.$string.'something';
    }

    return $string;
}
```

I can see everyone else already beat me to it, so here is the docs for ternary:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: because he might only want to show if its true and nothing if false.

Comment: @hanoncs - what on earth did you just suggest then? If he doesn't want to define the false handling then don't use a ternary plain and simple. There's no "might" in his question. It's clear he only wants to append on true but thinks self re-declaration is wasteful for false. So if that's a concern, he's running a function to check anyhow so why not just say $string = condition() and have that function give the final results of the string?